# Foreach jquery concatenar na tabela

Tags: html, jquery, foreach

Tenho um **AJAX** que no `success` traz um `response`:

```js
$(response).each(function(i) {
  alert(response[i]);
  $('#tbody').html(
    "<tr>" +
    "<td>" + response[i].id + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + response[i].nome + "</td>" +
    "</tr>")
});
```

**Meu HTML:**

```
<tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
```

Porém ele está sobrescrevendo os dados, ou seja, **quando `i=0`** fica assim:

```
<tbody id="tbody">
  <tr>
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td> Maria </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

**quando `i=1`**:

```
<tbody id="tbody">
  <tr>
    <td> 2 </td>
    <td> João </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Resultado esperado:**

```
<tbody id="tbody">
  <tr>
    <td> 1 </td>
    <td> Maria </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 2 </td>
    <td> João </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que você está utilizando [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) e ele vai substituir a cada iteração. O correto é utilizar o [`append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/).

```
$(response).each(function(i) {
  alert(response[i]);
  $('#tbody').append(
    "<tr>" +
    "<td>" + response[i].id + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + response[i].nome + "</td>" +
    "</tr>")
});
```

O [`append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) pega o que já tem e adiciona um novo.

Comment: Gilmar, você poderia adicionar links para a documentação oficial para sua resposta ficar ainda melhor

Comment: Link da documentação append jquery. http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: Eu me referia a editar sua resposta, mas tudo bem. Eu adiciono.